# C# como modificar array multidimensional

Tags: array, lista, tuplas

Estoy implementando un algoritmo voraz y parte de su proceso es comparar un conjunto de elementos con subconjuntos de esos mismos elementos. Lo que hace es contar el numero de subconjuntos que existen de cada conjunto principal y almacenarlo en una dimensión de la matriz.
He probado diversas técnicas, pero siempre me atasco en alguna de ellas.La idea es tener un array, matriz o lo que sea, que me permita asignar un contador a cada fila de esa matriz. (podría añadir una columna mas, pero no me parece elegante)
Ahora estoy en este punto:

Nota. En python está chupao hacerlo, pero este algoritmo es parte de un programa de Windows Forms y tiene que ser en C#

```
List<Tuple<int,int[]> conjuntos= new List<Tuple<int, int[]>>(); // lista de tuplas, con un contador y un array de enteros
List<int[]> subconjuntos=new List<int[]>(); // lista de array de enteros

PoblarLista(conjuntos);  //no interesa el método, solo que genera una lista de arrays
PoblarLista(subconjuntos);

// Ahora para cada fila de la tupla quiero contar cuantos subconjuntos tiene y almacenarlos en la propia tupla.
//
foreach(var conj in conjuntos)
{
   int[] fila = conj.Item2;
   foreach(var subconj in subconjuntos)
   {
      var compara= fila.Intersect(subconj);
      int coincide= compara.Count();
      if(coincide >= umbral)  //para cada coincidencia aumento un contador
         conj.Item1 += conj.Item1;// Aqui da error, dice que es solo de lectura 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede modificar el Item de un [Tuple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=net-6.0), es como intentar modificar la *Key* de una lista.

Te sugiero aproveches un poco más el potencial de c# usando [Dictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) y alguna clase que te ayude a modelar tu necesidad.

Te dejo un test unitario ([MSTest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest)).

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CuentaIntersectTest()
    {
        var conjuntos = new Dictionary<int, ListaConContador>();
        var subconjuntos = new List<int[]>();

        //poblar conjuntos
        conjuntos.Add(1, new ListaConContador() { Contador = 0, Lista = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } });
        conjuntos.Add(2, new ListaConContador() { Contador = 0, Lista = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 } });
        conjuntos.Add(3, new ListaConContador() { Contador = 0, Lista = new int[] { 20, 21, 22 } });
        conjuntos.Add(4, new ListaConContador() { Contador = 0, Lista = new int[] { 10, 11, 12 } });

        //poblar subconjuntos
        subconjuntos.Add(new int[] { 3, 30 });
        subconjuntos.Add(new int[] { 10, 3, 1 });
        subconjuntos.Add(new int[] { 11 });
        subconjuntos.Add(new int[] { 12 });

        int umbral = 1; //asumo que será un valor a superar para comenzar a contar.

        foreach (var conj in conjuntos)
        {
            int[] fila = conj.Value.Lista;
            foreach (var subconj in subconjuntos)
            {
                var compara = fila.Intersect(subconj);
                int coincide = compara.Count();
                
                if (coincide >= umbral)
                    conj.Value.Contador++;
            }
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(2, conjuntos[1].Contador);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, conjuntos[2].Contador);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, conjuntos[3].Contador);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, conjuntos[4].Contador);
    }
```

Y la definición de la clase ListaConContador

```
public class ListaConContador
{
    public int Contador { get; set; }
    public int[] Lista { get; set; }

    public ListaConContador() 
    {
        Lista = new int[] { };
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me deje llevar porqué tengo algo parecido hecho en python, pero luego cai en la cuenta de que con una clase lo solventaba perfectamente. Lo he estado probando y justo venia a autocontestarme, pero has sido mas rápido. :-)

Comment: Buenísimo que ya lo estabas resolviendo por ese lado! Saludos!